# Determine if hash1 data exists in hash2 in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Say I have 2 hashes:

```
my %hash1 = ('file1' => 123, 'file3' => 400);
my %hash2 = ('file1' => 123, 'file2' => 300, 'file3' => 400);
```

What's the best way to determine if the key/value pairs in hash1 do not exist in hash2?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "key/value pairs" do you mean that both the key *and* the value have to be the same in both hashes?

Comment: So, in your example, all the key/value pairs in `%hash1` DO exist in `%hash2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %hash1 = ('file1' => 123, 'file3' => 400);
my %hash2 = ('file1' => 123, 'file2' => 300, 'file3' => 400);

foreach my $key (keys %hash1){
    print "$key\t$hash1{$key}\n" if !exists $hash2{$key};
    print "$hash1{$key}\n" if $hash1{$key} != $hash2{$key};
}
```

Which outputs nothing, as all the keys that exist in `%hash1` also exist in `%hash2`, and all the values for each key are the same

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the new pairwise features of [**`List::Util`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil#KEY/VALUE_PAIR_LIST_FUNCTIONS). (Well, actually I've been using my own version of them for a long time, even before `List::Pairwise`.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

no warnings 'experimental';
use List::Util qw<pairgrep pairmap>;

my %hash1 = ('file1' => 123, 'file3' => 402);
my %hash2 = ('file1' => 123, 'file2' => 300, 'file3' => 400);

my @comp 
    = pairmap  { $a } 
      pairgrep { not ( exists $hash2{ $a } and $hash2{ $a } ~~ $b ) }
      %hash1
    ;
```

Note that `$hash1{file3}` was changed to 402, to make a solution set.